# Why behaviour pattern is named so?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) says, behavioural design pattern is

> In software engineering, behavioral design patterns are design
>   patterns that identify common communication patterns between objects
>   and realize these patterns.

Meaning of behaviour is

> the way in which one acts or conducts oneself, especially towards
>   others.

Hope there is difference in conduct and communication. Any idea why they named so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Conduct" implies a single entity acting on its own volition.  "Communication" is a way of conducting oneself with others.   In your example they are looking for patterns in the conduct of multiple entities, and measuring the behavior during their communication.

Comment: Great Answer. What does realize this pattern mean? Do they mean they will implement that or use that?

Comment: to realize something is to make it real.  After identifying something as a concept, you fashion it to exist in reality.